# UML how to represent a class concern/module/extension

Tags: ruby, swift, uml

I am talking about concern/module/extensions as they exist in Ruby and Swift for example.

A Ruby module is something that a class can include (= add the module functions as its own instance methods) or extend (add the module functions as its own class methods).

A swift extension is also an add-on for class, typically when you want to add a functionality you would first define the prototype, then implement it in an extension.

(please correct me if I'm wrong)

How would you represent such a Ruby module/Swift extension in UML, and its link to the class it is included in/it extends ?

Comment: I am designing with Visual Paradigm, there is a list of "stereotypes" that maybe could fit : `auxiliary`, `agent`, `capability`, `delegate`,...?

Answer (score 4):

I also don't know a standard for this, but would model it like this:

[image]

A `Realize` relation with an `<<import>>` stereotype. Maybe the `Realize` is too strong in the context and a simple `Dependency` but still with that stereotype would be better.

Not everything is available natively in UML. But like in any language, if you don't have a single word for a thing you can make constructs that describe the thing. You are rather free in choosing your vocabulary. Only you should be consistent in the domain where you use such a paraphrase.